# Where is the value the user has given?

Tags: javascript, node.js

First of all I'm the beginner the `node.js` and trying to understand:

```
bot.dialog('askForLocation', [
  function (session, args) {
    if (args && args.reprompt) {
      builder.Prompts.text(session, "Enter a proper location");
    } else {
      builder.Prompts.text(session, "What's your meeting location?");
    }
  },
```

How can I get the user's input for later use after this code, let's say the user said `california` where is it stored and how can I use it in another function?

Comment: What's the builder variable ?

Comment: dude, -1 for not defining actual tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the proper way to get the `prompts` data as `response`

```es6
bot.dialog('askForLocation', [
    // Step 1
    function (session) {
        if (args && args.reprompt) {
          builder.Prompts.text(session, "Enter a proper location");
        } else {
          builder.Prompts.text(session, "What's your meeting location?");
        }
    },
    // Step 2
    function (session, results) {
        session.endDialog(`Hello from location name = ${results.response}!`);
    }
]);
```

See More Info : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-dialog-prompt